# Need help replicating a cool box

Tags: tcolorbox

I found a pretty cool box I would like to replicate and use in my report, however, the source code for this particular box is not available, and although I'm getting close to figuring it out, I've already put a ridiculous amount of time into it, so I'm hoping maybe one of y'all have an easy answer.

The box I'm referencing can be seen in the **Table of Contents -- Section 6 --** of the [tcolorbox Manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf). It's the small green "side by side" box.

I basically just want to reproduce the box width/size, and vertically-stacked text style, change the colors, and enter arbitrary text.

> Start with the used `\documentclass{...` and end the code with `\end{document}` so that it is compilable with pdflatex. Not all of us use `LyX` ...

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tcbsidebyside
[
nobeforeafter,
sidebyside adapt=both,
size=fbox,
drop lifted shadow,
bicolor, colback=black, colbacklower=white,
colframe=black,
colupper=white,  collower=black,
fontupper=~\bfseries, fontlower=\bfseries,
]
{AC}
{H}
\end{document}
```

Here's my alternate approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
[
nobeforeafter,
sidebyside,
size=fbox,
skin=bicolor,
halign=center,
halign lower=center,
colframe=black,
colback=black, 
colbacklower=white, 
colupper=white,  
collower=black,
fontupper=~\bfseries, 
fontlower=\bfseries,
]
\textbf {AC}
\tcblower {H}
\end {tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

ijwmcb

Comment: I have no idea which box you mean, but the code of the manual is available: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox

Comment: @Ulrike small green one with the contents: LIB and xparse. Thanks for the resource too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code of the manual is online. Looking into it I guess you want this box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mylib}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,rotate=90] {LIB} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}

\begin{document}
\mylib{xparse}

\end{document}
```

[image]